# Returning polynomial coefficients from matlabFunction as an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, symbolic-math, polynomials, coefficients

Using symbolic math I generate a polynomial using poly2sim in the following way :

```
nOrderA=input('Power of=')
A = sym('A', [1 nOrderA])
p = poly2sym(A,x)
```

This returns a polynomial the order of which is dependent on the user input. In the case of the user input being 3 the output of p is given by

```
p = (sym)

       2
  A₁₁⋅x  + A₁₂⋅x + A₁₃
```

I intend to use this output as a function and do this as follows:

```
F = matlabFunction((p))
```

This value of F returned is

```
@(A11, A12, A13, x) A11 .* x .^ 2 + A12 .* x + A13
```

Here instead of the coefficients A11, A12, A13 as separate inputs to the functions, I would like to have them inputted as an array of coefficients i.e.

the value of F returned should be

```
 @(A, x) A11 .* x .^ 2 + A12 .* x + A13
```

where `A = [A11,A12,A13]`

How should I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `coeffs` function:

```
C = coeffs(p)
```

returns coefficients of the polynomial `p` with respect to all variables determined in `p` by `symvar`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like the function F to accept an array of coefficients as **input** and not individual values like A11 ... Is that possible ?

Comment: you can either use the smybolic polynomial as input and extract the coefficients within your function or use the output of the `coeffs` funciton.
The function returns an array already:

Find all coefficients of 3x2.

`syms x`

`c = coeffs(3*x^2, 'All')`

`c = [ 3, 0, 0]`